# Why is my React + NodeJS not reachable on local network?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, package.json

I have a React / NodeJS app in my local environment and it works fine.

Express: http://localhost:4000
React: http://localhost:3000 but also http://123.12.12.12:3000 (LAN)

I have set a proper proxy in my React package.json.

It works fine and my colleagues can access the app.

But then I build the app and they serve -s build without proxy in package.json. It gives me http://123.13.13.13:5000

I can access it on my laptop but my colleagues can not.

It says connection refused due to timeout.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Check if your 5000 port is open to external access

Comment: how to check that

Comment: Is your OS linux?

Comment: windows 10......

Comment: You can follow this tutorial and open the port. https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html Then let me know if it worked